# JQuery - Create element and concatenate it to other html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the code `var check = $($.parseHTML("<input type=\"checkbox\" />")[0]);` I would like to know why:

- `check.html()` is a empty string
- `check[0]` is `<input type="checkbox"></input>` AND
- `check[0] + 'test'` is `"[object HTMLInputElement]test"`

And I would to know what do I have to do to get `<input type="checkbox"></input>test`

Comment: Are you looking to just add a checkbox to your existing HTML?

Comment: check[0] + 'test' as you concat different object type check[0] is converted into string.

Comment: Fix your input tag: `<input type="checkbox" value="test" />`  There is no closing tag (it is a *void element*) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` will be a jQuery wrapper around an `<input type="checkbox" />` element. As such, it contains no other elements, so `check.html()` returns `""`. Remember that `.html()` returns the stuff *inside* the element, not the element itself.

All jQuery wrappers are list-like; in this case, the list has only one element (that `input`), which is found at `check[0]`.

```
check[0] + 'test'
```

means "add a string to this `input` element". As-is, that makes no sense, so the string representation of `input` is used instead (`"[object HTMLInputElement]"`).

If you want the string "test" after the element, you'll need to add that element to the DOM, then append the string *after* it.

```
$('#somecontainer').append(check).append("test");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just drop the `parseHTML`.

```
$('<input type="checkbox" />')  // Gives you an array of new elements

$('<input type="checkbox" />')[0] // The new input element
```

From there... don't concatenate HTML.  Insert the elements where they are supposed to be.  Otherwise you may run into issues with escaping, should you use text in the context of HTML.